# error uploading file to S3 :missing required :bucket option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I 'm trying to upload data to s3 using paperclip. I keep getting the following error

> missing required :bucket option
>
> app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:64:in `block in update'
>   app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:63:in`update'

I have updated my config/environments/development.rb with appropriate s3 credentials. I 'm getting this error when running my app on local, have not yet tried it on Heroku.
Any suggestions what else am I missing?

**document.rb**

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :documentId, :name, :docstack

  has_attached_file :docstack, styles: {
    thumb: '200x200',
    medium: '33x300>'
  }
end
```

**development.rb**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['bucket'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['123'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['key']
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Referring to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#define-the-file-attribute-in-the-model) blog
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the `ENV` variable values?

Try adding this file,

```
# /config/initializers/env.rb

ENV['s3_bucket'] = 'XXX'
ENV['s3_access_key_id'] = 'XXX'
ENV['s3_secret_access_key'] = 'XXX'
```

and this code to `development.rb` file,

```
# /config/environments/development.rb

config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['s3_bucket'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['s3_access_key_id'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['s3_secret_access_key']
  }
}
```

and then add the `env.rb` to your `.gitignore` file so your credentials are not stored in GIT,

```
# /.gitignore

/config/initializers/env.rb
```

Comment: I have already added the aws credentials to development.rb. I dont see env.rb in my initializers folders.

Comment: You would need to create the `env.rb` because it doesn't exist yet. The `env.rb` file sets the values for `ENV['s3_bucket']`, `ENV['s3_access_key_id']` and `ENV['s3_secret_access_key']`. You would replace the `XXX` values with your credentials. Do your credentials currently look like this `:bucket => ENV['my_bucket']` or this `:bucket => 'my_bucket'`?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem before and seen the same error message.  Be sure to check in the rails console whether the ENV variables are properly set ("$ ENV['AWS_BUCKET']").  Despite properly exporting the env variables, one of mine was returning nil.  After restarting Terminal, it worked as expected..